# Optimizing GridDB for high load scenarios - Dealing with overload issues

Tags: c++, database, performance, griddb

I'm working on a high-performance application that heavily relies on GridDB for data management, but I'm experiencing challenges when it comes to handling high load scenarios.

- My application experiences bursts of high traffic and data input, leading to performance degradation and occasional overload issues in GridDB.
- I'm looking for insights into optimizing GridDB to ensure it can handle these high load scenarios effectively.
- My GridDB version v5.2
- Programming language: C++

**Specific Challenges:**

- Data ingestion bottlenecks during traffic spikes: I'm seeking ways to handle sudden increases in data input.
- High query loads: Queries can become slow during peak usage, and I need to ensure quick response times.
- I reread the GridDB documentation for performance tuning tips. But it still hasn't had the effect I wanted.
- I've edited the configuration settings in GridDB to the best of my knowledge.
- I've implemented connection pooling for better resource management.